# Text not wrapping in container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My text is not being wrapped in the container. I am working with `bootstrap`.

Here is the link to the website.
http://www.gloria9.com/html/terms_n_onditions.html

This is the code I am using for the `p tag`. (Please note that the text right under **this is working absolutely fine and the same properties are being applied to it**)

```
.terms_n_onditions p {
    text-align:left;
    color:#000;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: 'SEGOEUIL_r_lighter';
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have set any width for the element, So when do you expect it to wrap..? try `word-wrap:break-word`

Comment: Yeah, `word-wrap: break-word` on that element is the right answer. I'm not sure why this is a problem though, so I won't answer.

Comment: YES! Thank you! word-wrap: break-word works! Thank you!

Comment: Even if that works, it's still a bit weird. Have you tried to rewrite the text inside your `p` from scratch? It solved the problem for me. Maybe there are a few weird characters in it...

Comment: In the html you seem to have `&nbsp;` between every word in that paragraph. That's the issue.

Comment: @Joonas has it, it's the spaces

Answer (score 0):

if you inspect that paragraph with your dev tools you';; realize that the text has several non-breaking spaces added to your text, I assume you probably copy and paste that content from word and that's how typically those extra things get added.

This is what your paragraph has in it:

```
These&nbsp;terms&nbsp;and&nbsp;
```

see all those   (non-breaking spaces)make sure you type the content or make sure you don't get crap added to the content if you copy and paste. And use your chrome dev tools